# How to execute multiple of the SAME function in Google Apps Script Editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am creating a workbook where different individuals have access to just 1 sheet (about 10 of these sheets total), which all feed a master productivity dashboard that is owned by a manager. I am using the following script to allow these individuals to select multiple items from a dropdown list in their unique sheet:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var oldValue;
  var newValue;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (activeCell.getColumn() == 7 && ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId() ==
    "12345678") {
    newValue = e.value;
    oldValue = e.oldValue;
    if (!e.value) {
      activeCell.setValue("");
    } else {
      if (!e.oldValue) {
        activeCell.setValue(newValue);
      } else {
        activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ', ' + newValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The spreadsheet names are going to change as people retire/are brought in, so the function is locating the sheet with the GID (in this case: "12345678"). The issue is that we need every sheet to be included and no matter what I try it will only pick up 1 GID. Does anyone know how to solve this issue for running the same function across multiple sheets?

Comment: Your use of a constant here is the cause of this only picking up one GID. Seems to me hat you'll need to get the value of THIS PERSON's Sheet ID at this point.  I see you've also hardcoded the Column Number (7).  I suggest setting a top-level constant (for example, const DROPLIST_COLUMN = 7) and then referencing that value here (...getColumn() == DROPLIST_COLUMN).  You'll thank yourself later.  As for your question, we would need to know how "12345678" was derived.  Or need to know how to identify THIS PERSON's sheet.  Maybe restate the question?

Comment: In addition to above, this does not look like a performance question.  Please, at a minimum, edit the question to remove that performance tag and add google-apps tag.  These tags will cause your question to be reviewed by experts in the area, or at least people who have some knowledge.  Performance won't help you here.

Comment: thanks Dennis, will do! So I just copied the GID off the end of the URL when you click on let's say the sheet for "Stephanie". The URL was: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...edit#gid=12345678
The "12345678" changes for each sheet. I chose to identify THIS PERSON's sheet with the GID because the original code used the sheet name (see below), which would not work because "Sheet1" is constantly being renamed. 
ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet1")

I will try to play around with the top-level constant piece.

Comment: Welcome! After considering this question I don't understand when you say «*The issue is that we need every sheet to be included and no matter what I try it will only pick up 1 GID*», could you please clarify it? Assuming that you want to run this trigger over different sheets, you could hardcode their IDs in the same way as `12345678`. If that doesn't work for you please share what is your end goal in this scenario.